# Align text with link under thumbnail and align thumbnail at top left

Tags: html, css

My code is below, at the bottom there is a thumbnail, I would like the download link and text to appear below the thumbnail, and have the thumbnail appear in the left top of the black background below the header/banner. Can someone help?

```
<body 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<br>
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" style="text-align: center">
<tr>
  <td height="70" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000">
    <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/756/23511757696_469b593243_b.jpg" </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
              <a href="https://facebook.com/PhotographyBok" target="_"><input 
type="button" value="Timeline"/></a>
      <a href="https://500px.com/marcus_bok" target="_"><input 
type="button" value="Portfolio"/></a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/251458316228/" target="_"><input 
type="button" value="Shop Now"/></a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/128953167177144/" target="_"><input 
type="button" value="Downloads"/></a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/info/" target="_"><input 
type="button" value="About Me"/></a>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/photographybok" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
                       </div>
                       </tr>
                       <td height="568" border="4" align="centre" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000">
                          <img align="left" src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5685/22966400834_ca5b8b1cae_h.jpg" class="img-with-text" alt="Texture Download" width="204" height="136"> <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zikce9elhkg2qi/12333083_10153200931056625_1694988016_o.jpg?dl=0">Download Photoshop Texture</a>
                       </td>
</td>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you include a fiddle? Have you considered not using tables for layout since we are in 2015 already?

Comment: I'm 100% new to html coding, so at a loss what to try, what is fiddle? sorry for newbie.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: did this work? http://jsfiddle.net/5vxzmfzp/

Comment: Can you explain how the hell download link gets generated there? Genuinely curious lol. Anyway, you need to add "vertical-align: top" to td wrapper and wrap both image and link in <div> inside the <td>. This should allow you to achieve what you want. And for the future: don't use html table if you have no actual scientific data or something to display. And don't ask newbie questions on SO, it's not a place for this.

Comment: You would need to restructure your table to achieve what you're looking for, or use some CSS hackery to force it into the desired effect. However, you really should ditch the table layout and learn how to make this, very simple, page properly.

Comment: @marcus.bok Here I think this is what you want, you weren't clear as to what was actually the header so I guessed. This layout should be put down like a suffering animal. But ya gotta learn somehow.... http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/y1jx6u10/

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language, every tag is denoted with `<>` symbols and is closed with `</>` symbols. You have many improperly written tags. I went through the code, closing (or deleting) the one that were not closed.

So now you have a table with 4 rows in it, where the fourth one is the text below the thumbnail, with the link. You can play more with table cell (`<td>`) placement, but following the advice from Flignats, you should learn some basic HTML/CSS layouts and replace the current table layout.

Here are few additional notes regarding your code, if you get into it:

- use indentation that makes sense
- you are mixing inline CSS styles and HTML attributes, use CSS files instead
- scripts are usually placed before the closing body tag, so they don't interfere with loading elements

```html
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <br>
  <table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" style="text-align: center">
    <tr>
      <td height="70" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000">
        <img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/756/23511757696_469b593243_b.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
          <a href="https://facebook.com/PhotographyBok" target="_">
            <input type="button" value="Timeline" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://500px.com/marcus_bok" target="_">
            <input type="button" value="Portfolio" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/251458316228/" target="_">
            <input type="button" value="Shop Now" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/app/128953167177144/" target="_">
            <input type="button" value="Downloads" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PhotographyBok/info/" target="_">
            <input type="button" value="About Me" />
          </a>
          <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/photographybok" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="136" border="4" align="centre" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000000">
        <img align="left" src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5685/22966400834_ca5b8b1cae_h.jpg" class="img-with-text" alt="Texture Download" width="204" height="136">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr border="none" align="left">
      <td>
        <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zikce9elhkg2qi/12333083_10153200931056625_1694988016_o.jpg?dl=0">Download Photoshop Texture</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
</body>
```